# SimpleDateFormat Always returning 12.30 AM

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I am trying to utilise the Calendar apart from implementing my own logic.

I am setting the Calendar value   and trying to get the time in a format, below is the code

```
String timeValue = "06/11/2015 06:30 pm";
SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm a");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();


try {
                calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(timeValue));
                Logger.d(TAG, "Hour is = " + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
                SimpleDateFormat slotTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mma");
                SimpleDateFormat slotDate = new SimpleDateFormat(", dd/MM/yy");


                Logger.d(TAG, " Date = " + slotDate.format(calendar.getTime()) + " Time is = " + slotTime.format(calendar.getTime()));


            }catch (ParseException parseEx){
                parseEx.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I am expecting `slotTime.format(calendar.getTime()))` should return 6.30 PM while it is returning 12.30 AM.

How can I get the desired output which is 6.30 PM , What mistake I am doing

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you have `.SSS` after the am/pm character, but you should get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is OK. The mistake is on the datetime mask:

- The ".SSS" field is too much. This is only to expect for milliseconds, and, as far as I can see, you do not expect milliseconds in your input string.
- The "HH" mask should be "hh" for 1-12 hours format.

Thus, let it be:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
```

Comment: Okay let me try with hh

Comment: great hh was the trick actually , I have changed HH to hh and it is working thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have an error with the String in the time format

```
String timeValue = "06/11/2015 06:30 pm";
SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a.SSS");
```

`a.SSS` // **.SSS** is for Millisenconds which is not correct in the String you are trying to parse.
I removed it and worked fine for me.

Comment: let me check , I have tried already , but let me try it again

Comment: jup, give a try and let me know @Nagendra

Comment: I have tried but I am getting 12.30am , but I want 6.30pm

Comment: @Nagendra use the right format: "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove milliseconds from your Simple Date Format (SSS).
I get a java.text.ParseException running your code.

Try using a Simple Date Format string of "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm a"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `DateFormat.getTimeInstance()`, `DateFormat.getDateInstance()` and `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()` as these methods return a `DateFormat` which will honor the users local settings (e.g. 12/24 hour system or date formats like 2016/01/01 or 01.01.2016). This is very important if you plan to release your app in multiple languages. Note that these methods also take a int as parameter with which you can style the resulting format (e.g. short format).

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) for more details.

A complete example would llok like this (creates a String like 3:04 PM on devices with English language and 15:04 on devices with e.g. German language):

```
String s = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()); // Creates a String like 3:04 PM
```

Comment: I have removed .SSS but still out put for slotTime.format(calendar.getTime())  is 12.30am while I am expecting 6.30pm

Comment: Still you should not build your own time format as this gives you a static result not honoring the useres preferences. Try my snipped replacing the new Date() with your time.